# Non-blocking method to start several threads and run a callabck on the parent thread when all children have finished

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

The main thing is that the callback should be on the PARENT thread and not called from the task, which is finishing the job (e.g. NOT like ThreadPoolExecutor's afterExecute() hook).
I'd like to have something like:

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
>>>>> exec.addAllJobsFinishedListener(someListener) <<<<<
exec.submit(task);
```

and someListener to have an Overrideable method like allJobsFinished()

Comment: is this a real life problem or academic assignment? If first, in parent thread invoke join() for all child threads, and then directly call allJobsFinished().

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov it's real life. But calling join() in parent will block it, until the child is finished. Now when I gave it some more thought, I start to understand, that what I want might not be possible at all.

Comment: one one hand, you don't want to block the parent thread - that is, it executes something. On the other hand, you want to execute a callback on the parent thread. How are you going to execute 2 works on the same thread simultaneously?

Comment: that's exactly why I said in my previous comment, that I started to think this was not possible. I wanted the parent thread to stop doing whatever it was doing, execute the callabck and move on )))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Non-blocking method to start several threads and run a callback on the parent thread when all children have finished

If you want the callback on PARENT thread, then I'm afraid you need to have the parent thread calling `exec.awaitTermination(...)`.  After you have submitted all of the jobs and the `exec.shutdown()` has been called, this waits for the all of the jobs in the thread-pool to complete.  If you want this to be non-blocking then you are going to have to do this in another thread (running in a different pool of course).

I don't see how it can be a "listener" running on the parent thread that is *also* non-blocking.  You could have a background thread checking which will update some sort of shared state (like an `AtomicBoolean`) to be `true` when the `exec.awaitTermination(...)` completes.

`ThreadPoolExecutor` does have `terminate()` method that you can override.  Is that not what you want?  Here are the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#terminated%28%29) for the method.  Your code would look something like:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor threadPool =
   new ThreadPoolExecutor(10, 10, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
      new LinkedBlockingQueue()) {
     public void terminated() {
        super.terminated();
        // do something magic
     }
};
threadPool.execute(task);
// ...
// need to shutdown the pool after you've submitted all of the tasks
threadPool.shutdown();
```

If the "something magic" code set a shared `volatile boolean` or an `AtomicBoolean` that the main thread could check, then it should work fine.

Comment: I do not see `waitForTermination()` in the javaDoc (either JDK 6 or 7) for `ExecutorService` or `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

Comment: Typo @increment1.  I've edited my answer.  It should be `awaitTermination(...)`.

Comment: I am not sure if `awaitTermination()` does what you think it does.  Afaik, it is only applicable after `shutdown()` has been called.

Comment: This is correct @increment1.  You submit all of the tasks to thread-pool and then you shut it down.  Then you can wait for all of the submitted jobs to complete.  Otherwise you can never be sure additional jobs will be added to the thread-pool.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. I've edited your code snippet to shutdown() the pool.The problem still holds, because the terminated() method seems to run on another thread.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `ThreadPoolExecutor` class is really good option for you and you can call `getActiveCount()` method to check for running threads without being blocked. [Also look on this article](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/java-thread-pool-example-using-executors-and-threadpoolexecutor.html) for example based on `shutdown()` and `isTerminated()` which is pretty simple and nice as for me.

What this solution does not cover is waiting cycle. Some kind of sleeping should handle this. Probably standard combination of `Condition` and `Lock` (look for POSIX condition variable example) is also acceptable solution for this but it lacks beauty of previous approach.

Look for this, I think it is right for you:

```
package com.journaldev.threadpool;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class SimpleThreadPool {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Runnable worker = new WorkerThread('' + i);
            executor.execute(worker);
        }

        executor.shutdown();

        while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
            // Put other work or calls here...
        }
        System.out.println('Finished all threads');
    }
}
```

Please pay attention to the following facts:

- `executor.shutdown()` just blocks new threads spawning.
- `executor.isTerminated()` doesn't block you. You are free to do other job.

Comment: I don't want the parent thread to be blocked (by sleeping) until the Executor Pool finishes all tasks. I start thinking that there is no real solution to my problem in principle.

Comment: Well, your parent is not actually blocked in this case, you can do whenever you want but you need to check somehow children have died.

Comment: `getActiveCount()` is an estimation only according to the javadocs.  `awaitTermination(...)` is the right method.

Comment: @chhh Please look at update, I have explained it in more detailed way.

Comment: @Grey I think what he indeed needs is just `isTerminated()` check without block.